# jQuery Uppercase word locator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to locate words for more than 4 characters that are written between `<p> </p>` in uppercase and add them a style (ex. italic).

I know about the function `isUpperCase()` but don't know how to apply it to check if the string is more than 4 characters.

```
function isUpperCase( string ) {
    (?)
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What you have tried? Can we see an example input and output expected?

Comment: Would be like.. Input: "hello WORLD", Output: "hello _world_". Can't locate anything about this topic, only how to capitalise the first letter of a paragraph.

Comment: Have you tried using a regular expression to find all matches?

Comment: first write the function to convert one line like that...then try looping with the whole page

Answer (score 5):

```
var ps = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("p"))

ps.forEach(function (p) {
  p.textContent.split(" ").forEach(function (word) {
    if (word.length > 4 && word.toUpperCase() === word) {
      // 4character UPPERCASE word
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot Raynos.

Comment: Ooops - *split* is a method of *String.prototype*, not *Array* and *forEach* is not defined in many browsers.

Comment: I can't see how that works at all. *split* is a String method, not Array. *getElementsByTagName* returns a NodeList of elements, calling it with split will first call *toString* which returns "[Object]" in IE (and maybe other strings in other browsers since it's a host object and can return anything it wants), reslting in an array of one member, the string "[Object]". So anything after that is not what the OP wants. 5 upvotes! But no -1 from me. :-)

Comment: @RobG I fixed it ;) It didnt work at all, whatso ever. I dont know why ale said "it worked"

Comment: @Raynos—who knows? Anyhow, many browsers support *innerText* rather than *textContent* so perhaps `(p.textContent || p.innerText).split(...)`

Comment: @RobG Browsers don't support `forEach` or `textContent`, that's why you need shims or use whatever other legacy browser support strategy you want

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex to replace any uppercase text longer than four characters in the innerHTML of every `<p>` element with that text surrounded by the markup you're trying to insert:

```
$('p').each(function(){
    var pattern = /([-A-Z0-9]{4,})/g;
    var before = '<span style="color: red;">';
    var after = '</span>';
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(pattern, before+"$1"+after));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eHPVg/

Comment: This regex also allows for a combination of numbers/letters and hyphenated words. You can reduce it to uppercase alpha characters only by replacing `[-A-Z0-9]` with `[A-Z]`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, like Rob said, I don't think Raynos's answer will work cross-browser and it also won't let you modify the matches within the paragraph.

Here's a slightly modified version:

```
var i = 0, ps = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for(len = ps.length; i<len; i++)
{
    var p = ps[i];
    p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(/\b([A-Z]{4,})\b/g, "<span style='font-style:italic'>$1</span>"; 
}
```

You can change the span code to be whatever style you want to add. Just make sure to leave the $1, which refers the original uppercase word.

Comment: (This is very similar to Aaron's except that it doesn't require jQuery and won't match caps that have lowercase letters around them "aCAPSa")