# JavaScript to make all-capital words bold

Tags: javascript

For text in any div with some CSS class, I'd like JavaScript to set capital words to bold font (not exactly the same as setting capital letters to bold, or you get **U**nusual **T**hings **H**appening). I'm trying to format pseudocode in some program documentation, so statements like

```
CALL thisFunction
```

appear as

```
CALL thisFunction
```

I found this, which is 90% of what I need: 
[Script or CSS to bold all words that are all CAPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500354/script-or-css-to-bold-all-words-that-are-all-caps)

But how to iterate over all divs with class .pseudoclass, for example?
I tried using this,

```
$("p").html(function() { $(this).html().replace(/(\b[A-Z]{2,}\b)/g,"<strong>$1</strong>"); });
```

Comment: Well, if you can find all capital letters, you can then wrap them in a `<strong>` tag (or `<b>` if you so wish). If you have a regex, it's just a `str.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my solution at [jQuery Uppercase word locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695886/jquery-uppercase-word-locator)

```
var i = 0, ps = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(len = ps.length; i<len; i++)
{
 var p = ps[i];
 p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(/\b([A-Z]{2,})\b/g, "<b>$1</b>"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if this formula `(/(\b[A-Z]{2,}\b)/g,"$1")` is working for you, then to iterate over all divs:

```
var divs = $(".psuedoclass");
var oldHTML = divs.innerHTML;
divs.innerHTML = oldHTML.replace(/(\b[A-Z]{2,}\b)/g,"$1");
```